# How should I write the same XML design using the Boost Library in C++?

Tags: c++, xml, boost, xml-parsing, boost-asio

**So, I want to write the code for XML using the Boost Library, but it should have this same repeating structure(The values can be changed, I can do it) but the structure should be like this only. Please HELP!!**

**This is the XML that I really want.**

```
<Details> 

  <Customer> 
      <Name>Rahul</Name>
  </Customer>  
 
  <BillTo>
    <Customer> 
      <Name>Abhishek</Name>
    </Customer>  
  
    <ProductName>BlanketSauna</ProductName>  
    <PID>BS100</PID> 
  </BillTo>  

  <Customer> 
      <Name>Rahul</Name>
  </Customer>  

  <BillTo>
    <Customer> 
      <Name>Abhishek</Name>
    </Customer>  
  
    <ProductName>BlanketSauna</ProductName>  
    <PID>BS100</PID> 
  </BillTo>  

</Details> 

**Here are the code and the comment which your understanding.**

    namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
    pt::ptree tree;

    //Customer_Without_BillTo
    //This is perfect, it will create 2 structure, like this
    /*
    <Details>
        <Customer>
            ........
        </Customer>

        <Customer>
            ........
        </Customer>
    </Details>
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        pt::ptree Customer_Without_BillTo;
        Customer_Without_BillTo.add("Name", "Rahul");
        tree.add_child("Details.Customer", Customer_Without_BillTo);
    }

    //But the main problem is here , it will not make 2 different structure, like this which I want
    /*
    <Details>
        <BillTo>
            <Customer>
            ........
            </Customer>
            <ProductName>..</ProductName>
            <PID>..</PID>
        </BillTo>

        <BillTo>
            <Customer>
            ........
            </Customer>
            <ProductName>..</ProductName>
            <PID>..</PID>
        </BillTo>
    </Details>
    */

    //Instead it create this structure, which is totally wrong.
    /*
    <Details>
        <BillTo>
            <ProductName>..</ProductName>
            <PID>..</PID>

            <Customer>
            ........
            </Customer>

            <Customer>
            ........
            </Customer>
            
        </BillTo>

        <BillTo>
            <ProductName>..</ProductName>
            <PID>..</PID>
        </BillTo>
    </Details>
    
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        //BillTo_Product
        pt::ptree BillTo_Product;
        BillTo_Product.add("ProductName", "BlanketSauna");
        BillTo_Product.add("PID", "BS100");
        tree.add_child("Details.BillTo", BillTo_Product);

        //Customer_With_BillTo
        pt::ptree Customer_With_BillTo;
        Customer_With_BillTo.add("Name", "Abhishek");
        tree.add_child("Details.BillTo.Customer", Customer_With_BillTo);
    }

    /*So, Please Help me to fix this issue*/
    //I really want this structure which should be repeating 
    /*
    <Details>
        <Customer>
        ........
        </Customer>

        <BillTo>
            <Customer>
            ........
            </Customer>
            <ProductName>..</ProductName>
            <PID>..</PID>
        </BillTo>

        <BillTo>
            <Customer>
            ........
            </Customer>
            <ProductName>..</ProductName>
            <PID>..</PID>
        </BillTo>

        <Customer>
            ........
        </Customer>
    </Details>
        */
```

**Please help me to write this repeating structure in new .xml file**

Comment: Could you share the non-working code? Also what it's printing instead of the above

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your reply. Please see the above I have to edit the post and added a more detailed description of what I really want. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use add_child() instead of put(), since you have multiple nodes with the same name.

Here's one way to structure the code to do it.  Create subsections and use add_child to insert them in your ptree.

```
boost::property_tree::ptree fill_tree()
{
    // I'm not sure if that's still valid, but some compilers needed
    // return value to be declared first to benefit from return
    // value optimization. 
    boost::property_tree::ptree result;
    boost::property_tree::ptree details;

    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree admin;
        admin.put("Name", "Abhishek");
        details.add_child("Admin", admin);
    }

    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree bill_to;
        bill_to.put("Customer.Name", "Abhishek");
        bill_to.put("Customer.Phone", "965845125");
        bill_to.put("Customer.Address", "India");
        details.add_child("BillTo", bill_to);
    }

    {
        boost::property_tree::ptree admin;
        admin.put("Name", "Abhishek");
        details.add_child("Admin", admin);
    }

    // etc...
    result.put_child("Details", details);
    return result;
}
```

IMHO, complexity usually means there is some issue with the design... This may be what's what makes you xml complicated to create and it will also make it complicated to read. Adding one grouping called "CustomerInfo" or whatever this "Admin" + "BillTo" information is would help somewhat by decreasing complexity of the code by 4, 2 for writing, and 2 for reading.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your prompt reply. Yes, I totally agree with you about designing ideasXML.  But this is what I have to create an XML in a new file.

Please see the above I have to edit the post and added a more detailed description of what I really want. Please help!

Your code didn't help me. I think I have mistaken to explain in a better way. So now please see the edited Post.

Thank you.

Comment: @AbhishekKumarSingh  Something looked wrong, I've updated answer  It still is the basiocally the same idea, though.  Use put() for unique keys, and create seperate ptrees for non-unique sections